# How to get hidden field array values?

Tags: javascript

I have multiple hidden fields of the form

```
<input type="hidden" class="mail-contacts" name="to[]" value="abc1">
<input type="hidden" class="mail-contacts" name="to[]" value="abc2">
<input type="hidden" class="mail-contacts" name="to[]" value="abc3">
```

Number of hidden fields can be different for different cases. How can I get the values of these hidden fields ? As this is an array so can't get it with

```
document.getElementById('')
```

I need to get the values of these hidden fields and then pass it as query parameter. Please help me out. How can I do this?

Comment: dear please read your question description

Comment: how about `document.getElementsByName` (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName)

Comment: Kindly, modify description.

Answer (score 3):

I imagine something like this should work...

```js
const inputs = document.querySelectorAll("input[type=hidden].mail-contacts");

// convert to an array of values
const values = Array.from(inputs, ({ value }) => value);

// or as query parameters
const queryParameters = new URLSearchParams();
inputs.forEach(({ name, value }) => {
  queryParameters.append(name, value);
});
```

See:

- [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from)
- [Document.querySelectorAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll)
- [URLSearchParams](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URLSearchParams)

You can use any sort of query selector. For instance, if you wanted all hidden inputs with name `to[]`

```js
const searchName = "to[]";

const inputs = document.querySelectorAll(
  `input[type=hidden][name="${searchName}"]`
);
```

Answer (score 3):

jQuery:

```
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'>
<script type='text/javascript'>
    var lst_to = [];
    $("input:hidden.mail-contacts").each(function() {
        lst_to.push($(this).val());
    });
    var str_query = "?to=" + lst_to.join();
</script>
```

[**jsFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/yzYNY/)

Answer (score 2):

```
 document.getElementsByName("hiddenfieldsname")
```

use above function , this wil return you the array of elements with same name

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
var array = getElementsByClassName("mail-contacts");
for(i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    array[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are using jQuery, try this:

```
var arrayValues = $('input:hidden.mail-contacts').map(function(){
                      return $(this).val()
                  }).get();
```